# Why is not a child unordered list inside of a parent unordered list item occupying the whole space available as of it's parent element?

Tags: html, css

The child `ul` is not occupying the total width available to it (same with its parent `ul` item container). Also, the hover seems likely not to effect its background colour at all, though the background colour property has been set on hover. I would be grateful if someone could pinpoint the basic concepts I am missing here and also help me to fix them. Here is my HTML code fragment (and here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svmoq7hw/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
    *{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
        box-sizing: border-box;  <!--Specifies an element should have padding and border included in element's total width and height-->
        <!--Content Box is the default value for the height and width properties-->
    }  
    <!--Resetter rules for browsers-->
    #bodyContainer {
    }
    body {
        border:black 2px solid;
        background-color : grey;
        padding:5px;
    }
    div#header {
        margin:10px auto;
        background-color : red;
        width:70%;
        -webkit-border-radius:15px;
        -moz-border-radius:15px;
        border-radius:15px;
    }
    div#header1 {   
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:80px;
    }
    div#header2 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:80px;
    }
    ul#navmenu , ul.sub1{
        list-style-type:none;
        background-color:#444;                  
        margin-bottom:20px;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
    ul#navmenu li {
        border:black 1px solid;
        background:yellow;
        border-radius:5px;
        height:30px;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:30px;
        width:33.33%;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
    }
    ul#navmenu a {
        text-decoration:none;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }
    ul#navmenu li ul.sub1 li {
        border:black 1px solid;
        background:yellow;
        border-radius:5px;
        height:30px;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:30px;
        width:100%;
    }
    ul#navmenu li ul {
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
    }
    ul#navmenu li:hover ul{
        background-color:#FC6;
        display:block;
    }


</style>      
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bodyContainer">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header1"><h1>Welcome</h1></div><div id="header2"><h1>You Get to choose better !! </h1></div>           
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentHeader">
            <p>You Select ... We Serve </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                    <ul class="sub1">
                        <li><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fashions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>WebApp Version Numbered v1.0. All rights Reserved.                    </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I though think actually it is occupying the whole width available to it only . I am only not getting a way to figure out how to match it with it's parent's width so that they can visually be on sync on the page and also how to fix the on hover issue.

Comment: try "width:inherit" this will inherit the same width from it's parent. on sub1 UL not sub1 li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svmoq7hw/1/):

```
ul#navmenu li ul.sub1 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Just make the entire `ul` 100%, not just the `li`.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: @user3655102, no problem! Mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green checkmark if this is the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the background hover effect by removing the last ul from your selector on line 72.

Before:

```
ul#navmenu li:hover ul {
background-color:#FC6;
display:block;
}
```

After

```
ul#navmenu li:hover {
background-color:#FC6;
display:block;
}
```